# Python time with milliseconds

Tags: python, time

I have a following datetime:

`d1 = 2015-03-21 14:50:54.0`.

While doing `datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` I get an error that `ValueError: unconverted data remains: .0`. How can I add milliseconds to the time? If it not possible then how can I remove milliseconds from `d1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%f` to grab the milliseconds part of the time string:

```
>>> out = datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```